# compress the size of electron application

Tags: electron, electron-builder

I have developed angular-electron app.Its a simple app but its size is 159Mb.I have used electron builder for building the electron app and included auto-update package.when I unpacked asar file,it had node modules .when I specified not to include node modules in package.json ,the size of the app reduced to 89mb but the application was not running  .
this is my package.json

```
{
  "name": "example",
  "version": "0.1.2",
  "main": "main.js",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e",
    "dist": "electron-builder",
    "electron": "ng build --base-href ./ && electron .",
    "build:electron": "electron-builder build --mac --win --publish never",
    "deploy": " electron-builder build  --publish always"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~7.0.0",
    "@angular/cdk": "^7.3.7",
    "@angular/common": "~7.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "~7.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "~7.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "~7.0.0",
    "@angular/http": "~7.0.0",
    "@angular/material": "^7.3.7",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~7.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~7.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "~7.0.0",
    "core-js": "^2.5.4",
    "electron-updater": "^4.2.0",
    "ngx-electron": "^2.2.0",
    "rxjs": "~6.3.3",
    "v8-compile-cache": "^2.1.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.8.26"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.10.0",
    "@angular/cli": "~7.0.7",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~7.0.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "~7.0.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.8.8",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "~8.9.4",
    "codelyzer": "~4.5.0",
    "electron": "^7.1.2",
    "electron-builder": "^21.2.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.99.1",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~3.0.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.2",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.4.0",
    "rimraf": "^3.0.0",
    "ts-node": "~7.0.0",
    "tslint": "~5.11.0",
    "typescript": "~3.1.6"
  },
  "build": {
    "appId": "com.electron.example",
    "compression": "normal",
    "extends": null,
    "files": [
      "*.js",
      "build",
      "dist",
      "renderer",
      "!node_modules"
    ],
    "mac": {
      "target": "zip"
    },
    "linux": {
      "target": [
        "AppImage",
        "zip"
      ]
    },
    "win": {
      "target": [
        "NSIS",
        "zip"
      ]
    },
    "publish": {
      "provider": "github",
      "repo": "Example",
      "owner": "y***y",
      "token": "1234567"
    }
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "**********"
  }
}
```

is there any other way to reduce the file size of electron app

Answer (score 7):

You can change `compression` level from "normal" to "maximum" in `package.json`:

```
"build": {
    "appId": "com.electron.example",
    "compression": "maximum",
    // other build settings
}
```

This should usually **save you much in term of app size** depending on your previous compression settings and also on how much static files and added features, codes and/or dependencies you have in your build.

---

### UPDATE

Anyway, If your app is relatively close to ~80Mb you won't save a lot, because that's generally the size of electron's build (containing node, chromium and API..).

Check `electron-builder` [docs](https://www.electron.build/configuration/configuration#overridable-per-platform-options) for more info.

Comment: Setting this doesn't reduce much of the size. In my case, only 250 kb is reduced.

Comment: Yes @Prayagk , to compare, It depends on your previous compression settings and also on how much static files you have in your build.

Comment: Decreased my size from 137.254 KB to 103.884 KB

Comment: @DominikVogt yes, this happens when your app is relatively close to the min size of electron's build ~80Mb (don't forget you have node, chromium and APIs under the hood..).